# Why has English spelling reform never caught on?

Tags: pronunciation-vs-spelling

- English spelling is notorious in (literary) language learning for being [chaotic](http://ncf.idallen.com/english.html). It would be better for reading and writing learners if the spelling were reformed to a more phonetic spelling like Italian or Finnish.
- other language spellings have had success with spelling reform. Chinese writing was 'simplified' in the PRC and was adopted universally in the PRC (mainland China) but notoriously *not* in ROC (Taiwan). Turkish converted from the vowel-less Arabic script to the vowelled Roman alphabet.
- there have been some unsuccessful reforms, for example German in the 1990's, which attempted to change some small handful of word spellings, which were used in newspapers and schools but just didn't catch on.

My question is why haven't any attempts at spelling reform worked out for English?

Comment: Because it's a Communist plot.

Comment: Tsk! This is a dupe and you know it.

Comment: @Mitch Which one?

Comment: @starsplusplus 3 of them: posting on Christmas, ask using the phone app, responding to your own question.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if you were going for the up and down votes on same question one. Unfortunately you need a positive question score for "ask on app" and a positive question/answer/comment score for the "post on Christmas using app" one...

Comment: @starsplusplus Well, yes, I was hoping for a minimal net +1.

Comment: There are somewhere between fourteen and twenty-one vowels in various dialects of English, and they are inconsistent between different dialects (e.g., General American and RP). We have five letters we're using to spell them. Most of the spelling reforms I have seen proposed don't really understand the phonetics of English vowels, and wouldn't improve things that much (although they manage to do the easy fixes like getting rid of "gh").

Comment: Two words: **Installed Base**. Why is there still Windows™? Why is there Christmas®? Why is _bête noire_ so hard to write? We have become addicted to print, and with it, addicted to consistent spelling rules. Befor Caxton, piipl spelt az they pliizd an nobody kerd.

Comment: @JohnLawler I find "installed base" to be a very plausible reason, but it doesn't work for the success of 'simplified Chinese' or Arabic to Roman for Turkish.

Comment: @PeterShor OK, that's compelling for not worrying too much about having a direct phonetic spelling, but there's still the complexity of rules, the exceptions on top of exceptions. I think my Chinese example is to show that a script that applies to languages as different as Mandarin and Cantonese can still have a common script and still be reformed, not worrying about the individual languages.

Comment: Turkish worked because Atatürk set up a committee of linguists who did a good job. The Arabic alphabet is a lousy choice for representing a language with vowel harmony, and that's not news. It was well known at the time, and it was all part of the modernization that swept Turkey after the fall of the Empire. Simplified Chinese is simply an example of what a truly determined bureaucracy can do if it controls all literacy education for a couple generations. We could convert to Chinese characters for English in the USA the same way, but there'd hafta be a revolution first.

Comment: @Mitch: yes, but I think all these incompetent proposals show that to get a spelling reform that results in a real improvement, you'd need a committee of competent linguists who knew what they were doing. And you won't find competent linguists to design a spelling reform when there's no chance that it'll ever be implemented. And incompetent suggestions just make the case for spelling reform harder.

Comment: @TimLymington, tchrist: Re duplicate, the other questions was about whether there had been _any_ attempts at reform. This question assumes those attempts and asks why they failed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A 'why' question is very difficult to answer definitively, especially when there are many social and political issues to consider.

But there is one reason that seems to separate success from not.

A single authority makes a reform easier to enforce. Since English is spoken in many different Nations (US, UK, Canada, Australia, etc) not under some common educational or literary authority and there are already different spelling standards, it is very difficult to decide what exactly to reform to and difficult to enforce.

The PRC government (likewise Turkish) had control over the educational and journalistic systems in those countries at those times (and tellingly not in Taiwan or Germany respectively).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's the history of the language, its complexity, etc. And the Initial Teaching Alphabet failed over here, too. But, above all, the English character was historically too individualistic - or should I simply say belligerent? - to conform. I'm not sure how prescriptive Johnson's Dictionary was for the eighteenth century; but a regularisation of spelling was, of course, one consequence of universal elementary education in the later nineteenth century. The full answer would take (and has taken) several books.

Answer (score 3):

In the late 1960's in the US, an educational experiment was implemented in many elementary schools. It was hypothesized that spelling English phonetically would speed up the reading and comprehension progress of young students. (I guess they were hoping that the "simplified" version would expand and continue on its own.)

It was a colossal failure. By fifth grade, the kids in our neighborhood who were in the program were about two years behind, and the parents were screaming bloody murder. (You'd think they would have learned their lesson with "Esperanto".)

(Sorry, I don't remember what the program was called.)

I guess you can't implement something like that because it's hard to pick a starting place. (Also, people generally don't like having things shoved down their throats.) Interestingly, the texting craze has begun the process in a way that will probably become permanent within a few generations. (Guess all the old books will be useless - can't wait to see the Bible.)

Comment: Other countries have done massive spelling reforms ... Korea, Germany, and Turkey have even switched the alphabet used. The old books (1) are all still readable by many people and (2) many get reprinted in new editions.

Comment: The Initial Teaching Alphabet was indeed a colossal failure in American schools, but every linguist knew it was bound to be as soon as they saw it. This is what comes of having micromanaged curricula designed by people with odd ideas about how children learn, and executed by people with no idea at all about how and why to do it. If you want to see something you could give to any American first-grader -- if you can get their attention -- try real [English phonemics](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) instead of a Rubegoldbergian monstrosity.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of barriers in the development and implementation of a reformed orthography for English: (from Wikipedia)

> - Public resistance to spelling reform has been consistently strong, at least since the early 19th century, when spelling was codified by the influential English dictionaries of Samuel Johnson (1755) and Noah Webster (1806).
> - English vocabulary is mostly a melding of Germanic, French, Latin and Greek words, which have very different phonemes and approaches to spelling. Some reform proposals tend to favor one approach over the other, resulting in a large percentage of words that must change spelling to fit the new scheme.
> - Some inflections are pronounced differently in different words. For example, plural -s and possessive -'s are both pronounced differently in cat(')s (/s/) and dog(')s (/z/). The handling of this particular difficulty distinguishes morphemic proposals, which tend to spell such inflectional endings the same, from phonemic proposals that spell the endings according to their pronunciation.
> - English is the only one of the top ten major languages that lacks a worldwide regulatory body with the power to promulgate spelling changes.
> - The spellings of some words – such as tongue and stomach – are so unindicative of their pronunciation that changing the spelling would noticeably change the shape of the word. Likewise, the irregular spelling of very common words such as is, are, have, done and of makes it difficult to fix them without introducing a noticeable change to the appearance of English text. This would create acceptance issues.
> - Spelling reform may make pre-reform writings harder to understand and read in their original form, often necessitating transcription and republication. Today, few people choose to read old literature in the original spellings as most of it has been republished in modern spellings.[28]

Comment: Wow, a -1 for this?

Comment: @Mitch The text has very little in the way of original content compared with how much text is just copied straight from Wikipedia.

Comment: @tchrist - in what way it does not answer the question???

Comment: I never said that Wikipedia’s words did not answer the question.

Comment: @tchrist -      The reason for your donwvote ?

Comment: [Our Help Center reads: “Do *not* copy the complete text of external sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own.”](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). There is very little original text here, very little original thought and synthesis.

Comment: @tchrist-     Don't think my personal opinion would be of much interest, while I find those in Wikipedia quite relevant.  Should I delete the answer?